# 'Add Solution': Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio, features, spwebconfigmodification

I have a WebApplication scoped feature and I am getting this error when I deploy.  I have searched all over the internet, and the answers I have found are not much help.  Here is the code that is breaking on me:

```
public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)

  {
     SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
     String ownerId = properties.Feature.DefinitionId.ToString();
     list<SPWebConfigModification> modsToAdd = new List<SPWebApplication>();

  //.....more code
  }
```

I have the scope set right, but I am not sure what is going on here.  I do have another feature that has a scope of Site.  Can I have multiple features with different scopes?

Comment: Is Partent a typo in pasting or is that really in the code?

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: You want functionality on "FeatureInstalled" or "FeatureActivated"? Try adding code in "FeatureActivated" event.

Comment: well i think that was it.  why would it not work in the install feature?  It will still not deploy, but the error has changed to a location i am trying to add in the web.config